# is there any problem to install different oracle 11g versions

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

is there any problem to install different oracle 11g versions. I mean if I have installed oracle 11.1.0.6 and i do install oracle 11.1.0.7 will anything conflict, such as oracle_home path, or any registry keys? will it cause any problem to .Net references to Oracle dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1.3.5 Multiple Oracle Home Support](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/intro.htm#BABHHAJC)

Oracle Database supports multiple Oracle homes. This means that you can install this release or previous releases of the software more than once on the same system, in different Oracle home directories. This allows flexibility in deployment and maintenance of the database software. For example, it allows you to run different versions of the database simultaneously on the same system, or it allows you to upgrade specific database or Automatic Storage Management instances on a system without affecting other running databases. However, when you have installed multiple Oracle Homes on a single system, there is also some added complexity introduced that you may need to take into account to allow these Oracle Homes to coexist.

Comment: that means that i do not need to configure something manually to use the right Oracle dlls in .Net?

Comment: You mean ODP.NET or System.Data.Oracle.dll assemblies that are referenced from your application ?

Comment: I have had problems once with multiple oracle clients on my workstation. Problem was in PATH env. variable where an older oracle client was on the first place among all ora clients. So make sure that some never version is on the first place.

Comment: Yep, I did too, and you're right. That's exactly the kind of problem i'm afraid of. I installed ODP.Net same version as the Oracle i had installed, and I hope not having difficult times with it. :D. Thnx man.

Comment: Take a look at this. Maybe it could help. 
http://cshay.blogspot.com/2009/07/microsoft-deprecates-oracleclient-time.html

Comment: it helped a lot, that was the answer i was looking for. Thnx again

Answer (score 0):

On unix this is no problem at all, using oraenv effectively selects the ORACLE_HOME that you want to use in your PATH. On windows, the installer adds the latest installed ORACLE_HOME\bin to the PATH variable. It should cause no problems when all applications use the registry in the correct way.

Ronald.

Comment: thnx, i'm using Windows unfortunately